# atomic property vs synchronized self

Tags: objective-c, properties, thread-safety, synchronized, atomic

My question is about `Objective-C` language.

What is the different between setting property to be atomic vs wrapping its getter and setter in `@synchronized(self){}` block.

Code:

Method 1:

```
@property(atomic, readonly) MyProp *myProp
- (MyProp *)myProp{
  // setup myProp
  return _myProp;
}
```

Method 2:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) MyProp *myProp
- (MyProp *)myProp{
@synchronized(self){
  // setup myProp
  return _myProp;
}
```

I guess that `@synchronized(self){}` is more efficient, because it only looks to `self` object to delay the accessor.

Am I correct?

Many thanks.

Comment: This one of this question where you should do a performance testing yourself or you will most probably get a random answer based on personal opinion not the facts. Soon on later you will get some answer, but from my experience it won't be trustworthy. My opinion is that `@synchronized(self)` is worse since you will increase chance of synchronization lock with other properties.

Comment: I kind of agree with the comment above, which is annoying, because I was also wondering this exact thing. Apple's documentation states that `atomic` is slower than `nonatomic` by quite a lot, while I've never heard of `@synchronized` blocks having significant performance penalties. I think overall `atomic` is more convenient and requires less work for greater utility, but the more your code gets run, the more you'll want to use `@synchronized` instead.

Comment: @MarekR: lets assume that we can control all others properties, e.g. there is only `myProp` property, no other properties exist. Is there any reason that `synchronized` is worse than `atomic`?

Comment: I think that it would be clearer if we understand how the compiler compiles `atomic`. Is is wrapped under another `synchronized` (with what object?) or  it does directly use an OS's semaphore